# Laravel, How to get product name from product table if the product id stored into Cart

Tags: php, laravel

Im using Cart named Gloudemans\Shoppingcart; (more about cart: https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart), inside Cart I'm storing many variables, one of them is id from product table, Im using Cart to show the items stored in Cart in Blade view, I want instead of showing product id to show the product name but cant use leftjoin in cart becuase it says Method leftjoin does not exist.

controller:

```
 $cartContents=Cart::Content();
  $products= Product::all();
```

blade view:

```
   @foreach($cartContents as $cartContent)
  {{$cartContent->id}}  // here I want to show product name not product id
   @endforeach
```

Product Model:

```
 protected $table="products";
  protected $fillable=[
  'category_id',    
  'storeinfo_id',
  'product_price',
 'product_name',
 'product_details',
 'product_unitsize',
 'product_unitsizelast',
 'product_unitname',
 'product_unittext',
 'product_unitserve',
 'product_image',
  'show'
    ];
```

Cart:

```
 Cart::add([

'id' => $request->cartproductid,
'name' =>$request->special,
'qty' => $request->cart_quantity,
'price' => $request->cart_price,
    'name' =>$request->special,

'options' => 

[
'size' =>$request->cart_size,
'storeinfo_id' =>$request->storeinfo_id,
'serve' => $request->cart_serve,
 ]
```

Comment: Please post you cartContents and products model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the doc:

> Because it can be very convenient to be able to directly access a
>   model from a CartItem is it possible to associate a model with the
>   items in the cart. Let's say you have a Product model in your
>   application. With the associate() method, you can tell the cart that
>   an item in the cart, is associated to the Product model.
>
> That way you can access your model right from the CartItem!
>
> The model can be accessed via the model property on the CartItem.
>
> If your model implements the Buyable interface and you used your model
>   to add the item to the cart, it will associate automatically.

So you have to associate the model that's in the cart, even better, implement the Buyable interface on that model. 
This is the example from their documentation:

```
// First we'll add the item to the cart.
$cartItem = Cart::add('293ad', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99, ['size' => 'large']);

// Next we associate a model with the item.
Cart::associate($cartItem->rowId, 'Product');

// Or even easier, call the associate method on the CartItem!
$cartItem->associate('Product');

// You can even make it a one-liner
Cart::add('293ad', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99, ['size' => 'large'])->associate('Product'); 


// Now, when iterating over the content of the cart, you can access the model.
foreach(Cart::content() as $row) {
    echo 'You have ' . $row->qty . ' items of ' . $row->model->name . ' with 
    description: "' . $row->model->description . '" in your cart.';
}
```

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: i edited the post, but it's all in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is clear in documentation.

Follow the link https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart#example

Just use in controller

```
 $cartContents=Cart::Content();
```

In blade

```
@foreach($cartContents as $row)

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p><strong>{{$row->name }}</strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: To add product by Cart::add('293ad', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99, ['size' => 'large']);
second parameter is the name

Comment: I know but Im not planing to add product name into cart!

Comment: you can save the name from product model it when add to cart
like $p=Product::find($id);Cart::add('293ad', $p->name, 1, 9.99, ['size' => 'large']);